# Как узнать версию BIOS?

Tags: c++, bios

Как узнать и вывести на экран версию BIOS текущего компьютера?

Answer (score 4):

Как информация о BIOS представлена определяется [SMBIOS стандартом](https://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios).

На Windows можно [выполнить `wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion` команду](https://www.maketecheasier.com/get-bios-version-information-in-windows/).

[На *nix есть `dmidecode` утилита](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/), которая умеет читать эту информацию. К примеру, чтобы напечатать версию BIOS:

```
root# dmidecode -s bios-version
4.04
```

[Стандарт](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.1.1.pdf) говорит, что начать читать можно из памяти с `"_SM*_"` в [диапазоне F0000..FFFFF](https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/77ac1e2c087f85c962ad5adeb9e476a515aced76/dmidecode.c#L5105-L5147). На Linux, это доступно как `/dev/mem` или [из файлов](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-firmware-dmi-tables):

```
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI
```

Чтение версии BIOS сводится к загрузке DMI (SMBIOS) таблицы из `DMI` файла cо смещением, вычисляемым зависимым от используемой версии SMBIOS cтандарта, хранящейся в `smbios_entry_point` файле. Из таблицы достаётся список структур, в которых уже конкретная информация хранится. К примеру, индекс строки с версией BIOS это [0x05 байт в записи с BIOS информацией (type 0)](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.1.1.pdf?page=30). Можно [посмотреть как `dmidecode` это реализует на C](https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/77ac1e2c087f85c962ad5adeb9e476a515aced76/dmidecode.c#L3385-L3423).

Answer (score 3):

Информация нужная тебе лежит в реестре в `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS]`.

Вот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HKEY rKey;
    TCHAR Reget[256];
    DWORD RegetPath = sizeof(Reget);
    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\BIOS", NULL, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &rKey);
    RegQueryValueEx(rKey, L"BIOSVersion",NULL,NULL, (LPBYTE)&Reget,&RegetPath);
    printf("%ls", Reget);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Появляются ошибки типа: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR".

Comment: @Махинс, перед литералами добавить "L" тут `RegOpenKeyEx(,,,,L"\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS", .....); ` и тут `RegQueryValueEx(...,L"Version", .....);`

Comment: Ошибки пропали, но в результате работы функции на экран ничего не выводится. В Reget записывается значение "0083F72C" (не уверена, что это то, что мне нужно), но выводиться через %s отказывается категорически.

Comment: Залезь в реестр и посмотри что у тебя в нужном тебе параметре, путь я указал выше. А чтобы в реестр попасть - Win+R -> regedit

Comment: Там находится значение V1.08, но в Regetсчитывается что-то не то. Ну или я тип преобразовать не могу)

Comment: Исправил, вместо `%s` взял `%ls` и убрал первый `\` в ключе. В ответе код у меня выводит корректно

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь)